# iPhone Settings Bundle with UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, settings

Does anyone know if you can create a settings bundle that uses a UIButton? I would like to be able to create something like Twitter in the settings but it doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do anything in a settings bundle other than the controls you can define in the bundle file, and you can only update values from user defaults in there, not run any of your own code.  A button doesn't fit that description.

The preferences for Apple's own software (I'm including Twitter in this since it is built into iOS) can be much more full-featured. Third party apps have their preferences in the ghetto at the bottom of the list.

If you want anything fancy in your preferences, you have to implement them within your app.

Comment: thanks that what i thought but figured i would ask the question anyways

Answer (score 0):

You can use a section with a single row as a button (sort of looks like one, too). It seems that is how the Twitter settings are implemented. This is the "Title" type of preference.

That being said, as far as I know you cannot run custom code from the settings app, which makes a button rather useless.